# Do I need to use eventDelegates or PolymerGestures.addEventListener?

Tags: polymer

I am confused, I expected to see `PolymerGestures.addEventListener(element, eventname, handler, capture)` somewhere in the source code?

view-source:https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html

Instead I see something like this

```
eventDelegates: {
  trackstart: 'trackStart',
  trackx: 'trackx',
  trackend: 'trackEnd',
  down: 'downHandler',
  up: 'upHandler',
  tap: 'tapHandler'
},
```

Does it mean that polymer already has gestures build in?

What is the best approach to make a left right `swipe` to next page event?

Comment: Have you seen https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/touch.html ?

Comment: Yes but they only have `touch-action` in common I still don't understand if I need to import `polymer-gestures.html` or use a global `PolymerGestures.addEventListener` ?

Comment: I think it is easier to try without and with it. I believe swipe is working in core-pages by default

Comment: In my case this is the only thing that works `window.addEventListener("track", function(e){console.log(e)})`  al this `touch-action` stuff doesn't seem to do anything. Maybe one of my elements overwrites something. But for now this will do thanks.